# Verification of Simultaneous Equation Solution

Tags: calculus

Could someone please cast their eyes over the following as I'm tying myself up in circles here, I think I'm just being a bit daft and can't see the wood for the trees...

Given:

$$ \frac{1}{nc} \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = \frac{x}{c} + B, y(a)=D, \frac{dy}{dx}(0)= 0, n>0, c>0. $$ n, c and B are arbitrary constants.

I'm trying to solve for $ y $ and $ B $ and getting in a muddle.  Here is my workng:

$$ \frac{1}{nc} \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = \frac{x}{c} + B $$
$$ = \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = x + B $$
$$ = \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = nx + B $$

Therefore:

$$ \frac{c}{y^n} = \cos(nx + B) $$
$$ c = y^n\cos(nx + B) $$
$$ y^n = \frac{c}{\cos(nx + B)} $$

And finally:

$$ y(x) = \left(\frac{c}{\cos(nx + B)}\right)^{1/n} $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \tan(nx+B)(c*\sec(nx+B))^{1/n} $$

Now, using the boundary conditions we have:

$$ y(a) = \left(\frac{c}{\cos((1)a + B)}\right)^{1/(1)} = D  $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}(0) = \tan(B)(c*\sec(B))^{1/n} = 0  $$

For $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ this can only be $ 0 $ when $ B = n\pi $, so, substituting into $ y(a) $ we have:

$$ y(a) = \left(\frac{c}{\cos((1)a + (1)\pi)}\right)^{1/(1)} = D  $$

Therefore we finally have:

$$ B = n\pi $$
$$ D =  \left(\frac{c}{-\cos(a)}\right)$$

If I then substitute back into $ y(x) $ we get:

$$ y(x) = \left(\frac{c}{\cos(nx + n\pi)}\right)^{1/n} $$

Does the above seem correct or have I messed up somewhere along the line?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unclear what you are trying to achieve in the question. You state you are trying to solve for $y$ and $B$ but also say that $B$ is an arbitrary constant - why solve for a constant? In your solving what is your aim? Which variables do you want to eliminate? What ones do you want to express $y$ and $B$ in terms of. You appear have three questions, two variables ($x$, $y$) and five parameters/constants(?) ($a$, $c$, $n$, $B$, $C$). With three equations you can eliminate 3 things.

You have made some mistakes at the start:

$$ \frac{1}{nc} \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = \frac{x}{c} + B $$
$$ = \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = x + B\color{red}c $$
$$ = \operatorname{acos}(\frac{c}{y^n}) = nx + B\color{red}{cn} $$

So you should have gotten:

$$ y(x) = \left(\frac{c}{\cos(nx + B\color{red}{cn})}\right)^{1/n} $$

Applying your derivative condition would then give $Bcn=\color{red}k\pi$ where $k$ is an integer rather than your statement (as $n$ is already defined in your question you can't use it again). Note that this means $B$, $c$ and $n$ are not actually arbitrary but are linked by this equation, hence $B=\frac{k\pi}{cn}$. It can also be used to simplify $y$ due to the periodic nature of $\cos$.

$$ y(x) = \left(\frac{c}{\pm\cos(nx)}\right)^{1/n} $$

(Depending on your situation there may be a good reason to ignore the $\pm$ altogether.)

Applying the value of $D$ leads to:

$$ D = \left(\frac{c}{\pm\cos(na)}\right)^{1/n} $$

Note in your working you put in $n=1$ without any justification at this step.

This would let you eliminate $c$ from your answer of $y$ as $c=\pm D^n\cos(na)$. This could also be substituted back into the value of $B$ from before. However like I said at the start your goal is unclear.

Comment: I see your accepted my answer. Hopefully this gave you some points to think about in clearly defining all the parts to your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thankyou.  Your working has helped me solve a problem I've been working on.  I've made some stupid mistakes - I thought I could absorb constants into B when clearly I can't.  B by the way was an arbitary constant from Integration.  I only showed part of the problem I was working on.  What you have shown has solved my lack of understanding.  Thankyou.